# Manipulate multiple selected rows in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, rows

I'm working with a WPF (MVVM) DataGrid witch looks something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Active" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ActiveCheckBoxTemp}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="100" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

With the Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ActiveCheckBoxTemp">
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Active, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This gives me a DataGrid with a coloumn of CheckBoxs at the front. 
Now what i'm looking for is a way to select multiple Rows and click on one CheckBox, and then the CheckBoxes in all selected Rows get checked.

Has anyone an idea or an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this exact problem recently using the DevExpress WPF GridControl. There doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box way to do this for either grid.

I used the PreviewKeyDown event on the column to detect a Space key press. I would then iterate over all selected cells and set their value to the focused cell value. It gave the desired outcome and I guess you could do something similar using the PreviewMouseUp event instead.

Let me know if you need more info.